# How to make from react component local working library (that render component to dom element, like jquery)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I have made SPA create-react-app. In the core there is a pharsal player with translations:

[image]

It has many dependencies like `wavesurfe.js`, `material-ui`, `lodash`, etc.

Under the hood there is a simple table with content:

[image]

Now I want to make a single js file for just a player. For add it directly to html file with  and it'll render player from DOM element
`<div id="frazy-player">Content of material </div>`

But whole app has router, drawers with heading (playlist), homepage etc. - that I don't need in `local version`.

How to bield react component with many dependencies to single js file, which will be rendered into given DOM element locally, in simple HTML file?

Working demo with player is [here](https://frazy.me/material/UUpEU_vKqHEwvfPIKylV/ru).

Comment: This question seems rather unclear

Comment: do you want to  create a React component to be the only one rendered locally?

Comment: please add information regarding the build setup (CRA? next? which framework and environment)

Comment: @Itamar I have found a same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51473061/converting-react-component-to-a-single-js-file-to-integrate-it-with-a-blank-html
Build setup is plain html file with element <div id="my-component-trigger"> table of content</div> and my component in single js file imported in the head of html: <script src="domain.com/my_component.js" />

Comment: and is this question answers your question?

Comment: @Itamar, I don't know yet. It's too complicated for understating. I'll try later...
I just showed it to you for clerify question. Did you understand now my question?